# Android layout folders: layout, layout-port, layout-land

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I'm not sure to have understood well the role played by the several Android `/res/layout` folders.

`layout`: general layouts

`layout-port`: layout for widget that must change for portrait orientation

`layout-land`: layout for widget that must change for landscape orientation

For example in the [Home](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html) sample application, under `layout-port` and `layout-land` folders there is only one `home.xml` file.

Have I understood right?

Comment: Some developers might not realize how important it is to master this concept, so thanks for putting this on SO.

Comment: My theory HTML5 will replace this stuff in the future.

Comment: Update: the Home sample application does not exist anymore. I don't know what replaced it.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If you are in landscape or portrait Android looks for the layout file in either the -port or -land directory first, if it's not found then it falls back to the default layout directory.

You can read about providing alternative resources [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). There are many more options than just land and port.

Comment: In this case, the other layouts do not change depending on orientation so they are just in the layout folder, whereas home is specific to portrait or landscape

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't some sort of orientation specifier for each property, to indicate different values for each. I understand that in the case of resolutions that could get messy, but since there's only two possible orientations (and always will be), it might be nice to not have to maintain two separate files for a layout if, for example, only one property needs to differ between orientations.

Answer (score 14):

If you put `home.xml` in `layout-port` folder, when your device is in portrait orientation it will use the file: `layout-port/home.xml`.

If you put `home.xml` in `layout-land` folder, when your device in landscape orientation it will use the file: `layout-land/home.xml`.

Meaning for different orientation modes like portrait and landscape... we use two `home.xml` files; one in `layout-port` and the other in `layout-land`. If on the other hand you want to use the same layout file for both, you can just put `home.xml` in the `layout` folder and remove it from `layout-land` and `layout-port`.

Comment: I've made seprate layout xml files for both layout and layout-land. But when I change the orientation to landscape, its layout-land file is not getting displayed by the android. What is the problem?

Comment: if you have two layout files in -port and -land and they don't switch when you change the device orientation, you probably specified android:configChanges="orientation" in the AndroidManifest.xml. In that case specify again setContentView() in the onConfigurationChanged() or remove that AndroidManifest.xml directive.

Answer (score 3):

Create folder in `res layout-land` or `layout-port`

**`layout-port:`** layout for widget that must change for portrait orientation

**`layout-land:`** layout for widget that must change for landscape orientation