# Android some buttons do not show when turned to landscape

Tags: android, user-interface

I wonder how can I display the same design when I turn the view to landscape view can anyone help me with this. I tried this code but it didn't do anything

the manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) 
{
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
}
```

Comment: Same design may not fit in other orientation, so you should design a new xml file to give the system a hint saying 'use it when landscape'. You can refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land.

Comment: thanks for the fast response 
:)

Answer (score 2):

Did you put the android:configChanges flag inside an Activity deceleration in your Manifest?

Try:

```
<activity android:name="myActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
</activity>
```

If you don't want any layout change when your device rotates, this should suffice, and android will just recalculate and redraw the view again.
If you do want the layout to be changed though, you'll need to load a different layout on your onConfigurationChanged function:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    if (newConfig.orientation == android.content.res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.portarit_view);
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == android.content.res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscape_view);
    }
}
```

BTW, you can have a decent preview of how it will look like in your layout xml "Graphical Layout" tab.

Comment: i put this one android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: It's OK, as long as you have "orientation" in your configChanges it will work.

Comment: i know that but there is some buttons in the bottom Disappear i don't know why

Comment: try to watch your layout as landscape in the "Graphical Layout", you probably need to create a new xml layout to make sure everything is shown. you can also post your xml layout file, and we'll see what's wrong in it.

Comment: You can also put everything inside a <Scroller>, this way you will be able to scroll down to the bottom button.
<Scroller>
...your current xml layout...
</Scroller>

Comment: I meant :
<ScrolleView>
...your current xml layout...
</ScrolleView>