# Design layout for fit all orientation

Tags: android, xml, background, android-linearlayout

look at my picture I want to design layout like that. look at my XML code below, I already design it but when I rotate it to landscape, the button is not fit the shop area(short) and linear layout in image price area is out of boundary(longer). I want it fit all orientation.why I am using button? because when I pragmatically, I can use it as onClickListener

1. how can I design this layout for fit all orientation?
2. Have any way to design this layout using XML code (not use background image)

[image]

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_all"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_all"
            android:layout_width="265dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_ic_mypage"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_mypage" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

1. Linear Layout for place backgroud image
2. Linear Layout for put button cover the shop area. easy coding onClickListener
3. Linea Layout for cover $ image area and put the image area.

Comment: To answer your "all orientation part" of your question, make separate layouts for the orientation. As long as the xmls have the same name, android will auto-switch between them upon orientation change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land

Comment: but it can't fit all screen size phone.

Comment: Which is why you should consider reading [this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html "this.") The android res folder also supports many screen sizes.

Comment: have any way to design this layout that not use background image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code what you looking for..

```
Also PL make sure you should avoid any length, height, width value is 20 dp,13 dp etc
```

This code will be fit for all screen sizes.

**main.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_main"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button_shop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/button_doller"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnShop = null;
    private Button btnDoller = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_shop);
        btnShop.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnDoller = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_doller);
        btnDoller.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (btnShop == v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "shop button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else if (btnDoller == v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "doller button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}
```

PS : if you get image small then create bigger image size icon, i have just used dummy only.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: yeah, it work find. but when setOnClickListener to linearlayout1 to make toast, and then I click to linearlayout2 it show toast as well even if it cover linearlayout1. how about that? actualy I don't want area around $ image do anything. @RDC

Comment: this isn't what I want but it bring me success.

Comment: @kongkea  sorry may be I couldn't get you properly,but I was trying best to solve your problem, anyway now you did it.. cheers :)