# How to get different layout in android when it's in landscape position

Tags: android

I am new in android my objective is that I have two different layouts one for vertical position and second one is for landscape position.

How can I use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations   :::   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Create in your **/res**  folder package with name **layout-land**
2. put **my_cool_landscape_activity.xml** in there

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

You should read android article about [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). They will show you there how to use resources to get this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just put layout for vertical screen in layout folder in res and layout for landscape screen in layout-land with same name.

if layout-lan does not exist just create it.