# Different screen sizes? (landscape)

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout, android-activity

**I want to make a separate landscape layout for each size of my original layout**

I have `activity_main.xml`. I have adapted it to be able to fit multiple screen sizes:

[image]

Now, I want to create a landscape layout **for each different screen size**. The android docs and many (Many!) stack overflow pages suggest to do something like this to create a new landscape layout:

[image]

But after doing this, I create a landscape layout for **all of the activity_main.xml's** I need a separate landscape for the large `activity_main`, the small `activity_main`, the xlarge `activity_main`, and the normal `activity_main`. By doing the method described everywhere, I end up with this:

[image]

And because this covers all of the `activity_main.xml`'s, I don't get the option to 'Create Landscape Variation`on my other versions of my`activity_main`.

So, how do I get separate landscape layouts for **each** already made variation of `activity_main`?

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Comment: have you try to visualize this in project structure . I can see in image that you are in android structure right now . you can find drop down menu above your project and select project from there.

Comment: Yes, I have. Here is a screen shot of it in project structure: http://i.snag.gy/L7VNO.jpg

Comment: yes now it has different folder right . so now here you can define your new folder or rename your current layout folder that suits your need.

Comment: @KDeogharkar What should the name of the new folder be to add?

Comment: according to the the docs you only have 2 choices. small screens and large screens. layout-land, layout-large-land -- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: @Tasos Is there any way to do this in android studio without having to create it manually? For example like the button which just makes another of the same layouts for a different screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your current structure is:

```
layout
layout-large
layout-normal
layout-small
layout-large
```

To specifiy layouts for landscape mode for each of these sizes create the following folders and put your size-specific layouts in there:

```
layout-land
layout-large-land
layout-normal-land
layout-small-land
layout-large-land
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer dabo. Is there any way to do this in android studio without having to create it manually? For example like the button which just makes another of the same layouts for a different screen?

Comment: Not that I knew. I would also recommend to create them manually, because then you know exactly what you did and don't need to assume what the button did for you. Just copy all your normal layout folders, add "-land" and adjust them for landscape, that's it.

Comment: Should I make it in the package view?

Comment: I recommend to use the project view, it shows you all directories and files.

Comment: Thanks so much dude. I have marked you best answer and liked your post. Thanks!

Comment: Except I have one more question...Can I remove the `layout` if I already have `layout-normal`?

Comment: Yes, you can. The default layout folder is just a fallback when there are no more specific layouts in your project. Just take care to define a layout for all above mentioned sizes, or, during runtime, the system will pick any of them with the nearest specification, which might not look as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this steps given in Image
[image]

select Project instead of Android where i highlighted in Image,
and expand your file from Projectname-> app->src->res-> and see seprate all folders

now -> right click on res-> new-> directory-> layout-land-hdpi

create like this

layout-land-hdpi

layout-land-ldpi

layout-land-mdpi

layout-small-land-ldpi

Comment: Thanks so much Survivor! I have liked. Thanks for the detail, I am sure it will be very helpful to others who come across the question. Great screen shot!

Comment: Except I have one more question...Can I remove the `layout` if I already have `layout-normal`?

Comment: the layout and layout-normal are similar it is batter if you remove layout-normal instead of layout it's my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on res then select "New" -> "Android Resource Directory". Give it the name "layout-large" and the type "layout". Copy "activity_main" of "layout" (in step 3) to the clipboard and paste it in "layout-large".
do the same for different screen sizes.

Android Resource Directory names are like:

```
layout,
layout-land,
layout-large,
layout-large-land,
layout-sw600dp,
layout-sw600dp-land,
layout-sw720dp,
layout-sw720dp-land
```

and so on

Comment: How will that make it landscape...?

Comment: -land defines the landscape orientation for the android application which is recognized by the gradle as well as the android os. give it a try so that you may find an answer

Comment: Put a modified layout for landscape in there and it will be shown, when the phone is on landscape.

Comment: I already have it in landscape, as my screenshot suggests: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iqrZu.png **I want to make a separate landscape layout for each size of my original layout**

Comment: ya i saw the screen shot create a separate Android Resource Directory for each resolution and add your lanscape xml inside it and your problem is solved

Comment: Except I have one more question...Can I remove the `layout` if I already have `layout-normal`? PS: I have liked :)

Comment: Yes, you can. the normal layout folder is a default call only when there is no more layouts in ur other layout folder

Answer (score 1):

you will find all information about [layout support](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html) . Look into [Using configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I have liked. Thanks for the detail, I am sure it will be very helpful to others who come across the question.

Comment: yes it has all detail not only about layout but also about drawable folder so it is very helpful while designing android layout with compatibilities.

Comment: Except I have one more question...Can I remove the `layout` if I already have `layout-normal`?

Answer (score 1):

> Android powers hundreds of device types with several different screen
>   sizes, ranging from small phones to large TV sets. Therefore, it’s
>   important that you design your application to be compatible with all
>   screen sizes so it’s available to as many users as possible.
>
> But being compatible with different device types is not enough. Each
>   screen size offers different possibilities and challenges for user
>   interaction, so in order to truly satisfy and impress your users, your
>   application must go beyond merely supporting multiple screens: it must
>   optimize the user experience for each screen configuration.

Please read SO Answers

1. **[Android layout folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land)**
2. **[Creating landscape layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815769/android-studio-creating-landscape-layouts)**
3. **[Android Landscape Layout](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-landscape-layout-example/)**