# TextView invisible in horizontal layout

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I am doing a tutorial of the big nerd ranch and it does not seem to work for me at this point. I triple checked my code with theirs but it won't work. The XML is a new content_quiz.xml file which is located in layout-land, it does work partially since the next button is showing up at the right place.

The goal is this:
[image: the big nerd ranch app]

but my app looks like this: [image: My app]

In vertical it does work though: [image: vertical my app]

The XML for the horizontal is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_button"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The java activity file is as follows:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_middle_east, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
        int messageResId = 0;

        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
                //Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // This is the OnClickListener, thus add QuizActivity
            }
        });

        mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        updateQuestion();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart(Bundle) called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause(Bundle) called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume(Bundle) called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop(Bundle) called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy(Bundle) called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I tested this on android 6 and 6.0.1 on both my phone and the emulator. Both give the wrong styling and discard the TextView. What is going wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land

Comment: share code where you set value into textView (R.id.question_text_view)

Comment: for test case remove `android:padding="24dp"`

Comment: Are you sure this is the layout used ?

Comment: add `android:configChanges="orientation"`

Comment: Let me feedback please .

Comment: Hi, tried that too, did not work, I now notice I have an error while in landscape mode `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa31c290`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya using **android:configChanges="orientation"** is bad way. Read more [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for your info.

Comment: @DanielsWrath do you see question text if click button "next" in landscape mode?

Comment: I recommend you to use a RelativeLayout as parent wraper, FrameLayout should be used just when you want elements overlayed

Comment: check the whether the textView is behind the linear layout or not in landscape mode

Comment: @Alexander No I do not. It does work in the default layout

Comment: @cgarrido Thanks, that might be more useful then. However the tutorial of theirs states that this should work.

Comment: @peeyushpathak How can I check this? I tried showing layout boxes but the box for the TextView isn't even coming up

Comment: set android:layout_gravity="top" to Push object to the top of its container without cahnginf its size

Comment: @peeyushpathak It does not show up if I add `android:layout_gravity="top"` to the TextView element

Comment: @DanielsWrath Check my answer below it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have made `Layout` using `Relative Layout` applied some changes. Use `Relative Layout` instead of `Frame Layout`.
>
> By default, the layouts in `/res/layout` are applied to both portrait and landscape.

If you have for example

`/res/layout/main.xml`.

> You can add a new folder `/res/layout-land`, copy `main.xml` into it and make the needed adjustments.

**Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="The pacific ocean is larger than specific ocean."
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="True" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="False" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Next Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is **`Portrait Screen`**.

[image]

Here is **`Landscape Screen`**.

[image]

Comment: @DanielsWrath Glad it worked Cheers !! **up-vote** it also thanks :).

Comment: I will if I get 15 rep ;)

Answer (score 2):

FrameLayout allows placements along Z-axis. It is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

**For your problem You should switch to  Relative/Linear Layout**

Comment: Thank you. However, how do I get the "next" button in the lower right corner with a linear layout?

Comment: @DanielsWrath You can do that using `android:gravity="bottom|right"` in `Linear Layout`.

Comment: @jaydroider I can do this indeed, but the other part of my layout needs to be centered. So I do not want to push everything to the bottom right.

Comment: @DanielsWrath Check my answer below it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `android:text="test"` in your TextView, so you can see if it shows up or not.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add a comment

Comment: I added `android:text="Test"` to the TextView but it did not show up