# Android: change listview item layout when changing orientation?

Tags: java, android, orientation

if I start the app in landscape mode, then it will use the landscape list item xml.  but if I start it in portrait mode and rotate it to landscape mode, it will use the portrait list item xml for both configurations.  I am using onConfigurationChanged to detect the orientation change, but I'm not sure how to tell it to use the correct xml file.  I have two xml files with the same name, but one is for landscape.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Trying to achieve this you should have **2 folders** for layouts one should be called

```
layout-land/*
```

other

```
layout-port/*
```

name your layouts the same

```
 File.xml
```

than just inflate them OS takes care of rest.

Also see this
[Android layout folders: layout, layout-port, layout-land](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land)

> specified android:configChanges="orientation" in the
>   AndroidManifest.xml. In that case specify again setContentView() in
>   the onConfigurationChanged() or remove that AndroidManifest.xml
>   directive

If your want to just Keep using onconfigurationchanged() than  just inflate appropriately.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: ok thanks.  I specified the two different folders, but I had to open the layout folder in the finder to see the two different folders.  Then I had to remove "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" from the manifest file.

Comment: You can switch your view in left Top corner if your using Android Studio. If you setting the Layouts manually you can put them in the same res folder.