# Difference between activity_main.xml and activity_main.xml(land)? How to change them at run time?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, orientation

I have two files `activity_main.xml` and `activity_main.xml`(land).

If my phone is in *portrait* mode, I want two run `activity_main.xml`.

If my phone is in *landscape* mode, I want to run `activity_main.xml`(land).

What should I do ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land

Answer (score 2):

Difference is `activity_main.xml(land)` is for landscape mode. If everything is there make sure your screen rotation is turned on!

Or else if you need to know how to do that,Create a new directory `layout-land`, then create `xml` file with same name in  `layout-land` as it was `layout` directory and align there your content for Landscape mode.

Note that id of content in both `xml` is same.

Or you can do that in this way,

[image]

[image]

Now the job is done!

[image]

But you have a single Activity and two views  depend on the orientation. View A might not have something in view B(if you have the same set of views in both xmls then you don't need this). If you don't have same set you need to initialize your views  in the correct way!

When you initialize your views you can do this by:

**For Lanscape**

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    //init  views in landscape 
}
```

**For Portrait**

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
 //init views in portrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the file activity_main.xml(land) and refer the activity_main.xml to the same java file!

Comment: what really!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK provides different ways to manage resources of android application.
Device supports two orientation mode:

**Portrait**

If you want to add any specific layout for portrait mode only, You should name layout file as 'xyz-port.xml'.

**Landscape**

If you want to add any specific layout for portrait mode only, You should name layout file as 'xyz-land.xml'.

Android system will decide runtime which layout to choose.

For your query below,

> I have two files activity_main.xml and activity_main.xml(land)

If you do not specify any like, `activity_main.xml` then, It will be used for both.

For more information check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please check the following link i hope you get the solution.

[google developer](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

[link 2](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/08/20/set-layouts-portrait-landscape-android/)